# Connect Amazon RDS with Heroku?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-rds

I have created my Amazon **RDS** in **Oregon** region. I have to configure this with my **Heroku App**. I am able to access **RDS** from my local machine. But this not happens with **Heroku**. I also don't have liberty to create **Security Groups** there. I am getting error as

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'RDS hostname' (111)

something . I won't understand that because by my local machine it was resolving host but not from **Heroku**.

Comment: Are you using heroku web services that host by heroku?

Comment: no. I just hosted my app on heroku, and created database on RDS.  so i want to link them

Comment: If so, you need to check whether Heroku allow apps to connect to external database, otherwise, you can only use Heroku hosted dbms.

Comment: yes, heroku allows to connect to external environment for database, that's why i was gone for RDS. only i had problem with the connectivity.

Comment: Only manage to find this. Quick glance show that you need SSL 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku
To enable RDS SSL you need to do this
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

Comment: ok thanks,  i will check with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Found solution myself, you just have to add inbound IP as 0.0.0.0/0 in security group for **RDS** to available it publicly.

Comment: How do you added the IP? Is this approach secure? Can you, please, provide more info and, if possible, reference some documentation?

Comment: More details from the Heroku documentation can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds#authorizing-access-to-rds-instance). Specifically, the document states "You must grant Heroku dynos access to your RDS instance. The recommended way to do this is to configure the RDS instance to only accept SSL-encrypted connections from authorized users and configure the security group for your instance to permit ingress from all IPs, eg 0.0.0.0/0."

Comment: See this post for Best Practices on using RDS database with Heroku App https://vel-lesikov.medium.com/migrating-from-heroku-postgres-to-amazon-rds-2e738e7730e5